# What is the difference between those two phrases

Tags: phrases

my girlfriend got mad at me for commenting "this is so going down" on a picture with a nude girl.

What is the difference between "this is so going down" and "i am so going down on this"?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Neither one is correct. Either one will get you in trouble with the gf. Best to just remain silent, and probably stop commenting on these types of pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither one is correct. Think about each sentence:

"This is so going down."

**What** is going down? The image? Something in the image? Nothing in this sentence means that **you** are being affected, and it doesn't really make sense in this context.

"I am so going down on this."

Unless you're trying to start another fight, you almost certainly mean **for** instead of **on**. You are "going down" (getting in trouble) **for** (because of) this.

Think about it this way. If you reword the sentence:

"I am so getting in trouble on this."

That sentence doesn't make a lot of sense, right? You're getting in trouble **on** something? Does that means you're standing on top of the image when you're getting in trouble? Does the picture contain an image of you getting in trouble? No. Instead, you mean this:

"I am so getting in trouble **for** this."

In other words: "I am so getting in trouble **because of** this."

Comment: The picture was not supposed to be on that website(9gag) and i was referring to the fact that the picture will be going down. But my girlfriend understood that i will go down on the girl. Is it possible for my comment to mean that if the comment was: "this is so going down"? Thanks a lot, i am not a native english speaker

Comment: So you meant that **the picture** would be **taken down** from the website? If so, then I suppose your sentence is technically correct- but given the context, it's definitely not the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks kevin, i was not aware that "this is so going down" could mean that this is so going to happen. But in no case can this mean i would go down on her right? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem. And yes, "going down" can be slang for "happening", as in: "What time is the party going down?" The point is that there are a number of different ways your sentence could be interpreted, none of which seem to be what you actually meant!

Answer (score 0):

The word "so" in both phrases means "definitely" in this context.

"This is so going down" means "this is definitely going to happen".

I've never heard or read the specific phrase "I am so going down on this", but "going down on" something where that something is a person typically has an adult-relations connotation to it.